# API request works from local machine, not on server

Tags: php, api, curl, python-requests, shopify

I have an interesting situation when calling the Shopify API. I use the standard procedure for calling the url and get the data, like this:

```
define('SHOPIFY_SHOP', 'myteststore.myshopify.com');
define('SHOPIFY_APP_API_KEY', 'xxxx');
define('SHOPIFY_APP_PASSWORD', 'yyy');
$shop_url = 'https://'.SHOPIFY_APP_API_KEY.':'.SHOPIFY_APP_PASSWORD.'@'.SHOPIFY_SHOP;
$response = Requests::get($shop_url.'/admin/products.json');
```

And I correctly get the response, parse the data and all works great. Now, when I put it to the actual server (Ubuntu 12.04), I noticed a weird message from the Spotify API:

```
[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)
```

I tried creating a new app, but still its the same. So the same file and the same set works on my machine, but not on the server. (only difference in the file is the path to requests library, `require_once './Requests/library/Requests.php';` for Linux and `require_once '..\Requests\library\Requests.php';` for Windows) As stated, I use the [requests](https://github.com/rmccue/Requests) library and I assume there has to be some trick where the library (or something else) rewrites the URl and it doesn't get to Shopify correctly.

I tried using CURL with the URL directly, and it works that way as well. Can anyone point me what might be causing this?

**Update: I moved to another library which solved the issue, but would like to know what was causing this since I had great experience with `Requests` up to this point.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure why is this happening, it appears the `Requests` library is stripping the parameters from `GET` requests, so I moved to `unirest` library and this solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm starting to use the same lib, and I stumbled upon something relevant right after finding this question:
https://github.com/rmccue/Requests/issues/142#issuecomment-147276906

Quoting relevant part:

> This is an intentional part of the API design; in a typical use case,
>   you won't necessarily need data sent along with a request. Building
>   the URL for you is just a convenience.
>
> Requests::get is a helper function designed to make GET requests
>   lightweight in the code, which is why there's no $data parameter
>   there. If you need to send data, use Requests::request instead

```
$response = Requests::request( 'http://httpbin.org/get', $headers, $data, Requests::GET, $options );
// GET is the default for type, and $options can be blank, so this can be shortened:
$response = Requests::request( 'http://httpbin.org/get', $headers, $data );
```

Comment: It still doesn't explain the difference of how it works locally and on production server (Windows dev, Ubuntu prod), so I suppose its maybe something else as well. Also, since passing parameters with GET requests is a relatively common scenario, I would expect some kind of documentation regarding this, since it appears multiple people are having issues. Thanks for your answer, it shed a light to this issue!

Comment: I agree there must be some other problem, but step by step debug to make sure the right url is sent is the only way I see to track it down.